# What is the meaning of $1_{a>b}$?

Tags: notation, characteristic-functions

What would this mean: $1_{a>b}$ .. Based on the context, it could mean "$1$ if $a>b$ else $0$", but it's the first time I see it so help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are right. This is called the [indicator function or characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) and it's a very common notation you stumbled upon.

Answer (score 2):

You are right.

Mathematical speaking it means:

$$
1_{a>b}  = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $a > b$} \\
0 & \text{if $a \leq b$}
\end{cases}
$$